# Can I set my sneak key to toggle mode only when on the ground?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the Accessibility Settings of my MCJE, there is an option to set the Sneak mode to toggle. I enjoy using the toggle mode in my Survival worlds or when walking in general, as I will let go of the shift key on accident sometimes if I'm holding it.

Yet, when I enter my Creative worlds or go swimming, the same rule applies, which is annoying because I would rather hold shift to go down when flying or swimming.

Bedrock Edition, at default, will only apply the toggle rule when on ground, not when flying.

Is there a way to set Java Edition to do the same thing: toggle mode when on ground to sneak, but hold to descend in Creative or in water?

Comment: @Ben I believe that that the answers there are insufficient. I've edited the question to clarify the difference.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Thanks for the edit, it helped clarify a lot

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 ahh yup, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this cannot be accomplished in *vanilla* Java Edition, as this feature is not built into the game. One possible solution is to look for a mod that does it, but it cannot be done in vanilla Java Edition.

I also wish this was a built in feature.

Hope this helps! :)